# Assistance required with PHP and XML soap response

Tags: php, xml

I'm junior to PHP and XML and require your assistance please.
How would I display only the values of the nodes in the xml response.
Example of what I would like to see:

```
name - Africa Direct
parent - 41711
invoiced - 1470002400
```

My code,

```
$wdsl = '*******';

$params = array(
            'username'=>'********',
            'password'=>'*******',
            'parent'=>0
            );

$options = array(
            'trace'=>1
            );

$client = new SoapClient($wdsl, $options);
$data = $client->__soapCall('get_customers', $params);
$response = $client->__getLastResponse();

var_export($response);
```

the results looks as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soap:Body>
    <get_customersResponse xmlns="*********/API">
        <s-gensym3>
            <name xsi:type="xsd:string">Africa Direct</name>
            <parent xsi:type="xsd:string">41711</parent>
            <invoiced xsi:type="xsd:string">1470002400</invoiced>
            <auto_topup xsi:type="xsd:float">0.000000</auto_topup>
            <contact xsi:type="xsd:string">0</contact>
            <invoices_due xsi:type="xsd:string">-2</invoices_due>
    </s-gensym3>
    </get_customersResponse>
   </soap:Body>
   </soap:Envelope>'
```